# Given irreducible markov chain with $P=P^n$, show that all rows of $P$ are equal

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

So I'm given that $P=P^n$ for $n=2, 3, …$, and I've deduced that for any distribution $\pi$, it must be true that $\pi P$ is a stationary distribution. But I'm stuck at this point, I've tried reducing it to a linear algebra problem by multiplying out the matrices in attempt to show that $p_{1,j}=p_{i,j}$ for all $j$, but this isn't leading me anywhere at all and the notation is getting messy. I'm wondering if I'm missing something simple? Any help would be great.

Comment: Your hypothesis is that there exists an $n$ such that $P^n=P$, or that for every $n$ it happens?

Comment: It is true for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for an irreducible positive matrix, the spectral radius is a simple eigenvalue. In your case, $1$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity 1.

$P^2=P$ is all you need, since it means that $P$ is a projection. A projection has only eigenvalues 0 and 1 and it is diagonalizable (you can prove it by noticing that the minimal polynomial of $P$ divides $x^2-x$).

As a consequence, $P$ is diagonalizable, has $n-1$ eigenvalues 0, and an eigenvalue $1$. In particular, it has rank 1, so all rows are linearly dependent (meaning that they are multiple of a fixed vector $v$).

To conclude, you can notice that the sum of the elements in each row is 1, so they must be equal.

Comment: Sorry how do we know that the eigenvalue 1 has multiplicity 1?

Comment: perron-frobenius: the spectral radius is a simple eigenvalue

Comment: Is there a way we can prove the matrix must have equal rows without using this theorem? I.e. is there a way we can deduce this from the fact that for a distribution $\pi$, $\pi P=\pi P^n$ is a stationary distribution?

Comment: @maths54321 no, take for example the identity matrix

Comment: Ok, as a side note, is it true that if a discrete time Markov chain has infinitely many stationary distributions then all rows of $P$ must be identical?

Comment: @maths54321 no, take for example again the identity matrix

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant if the chain is irreducible (since the identity matrix can't be the transition matrix of an irreducible Markov chain)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108596/discussion-between-exodd-and-maths54321).

Comment: @maths54321 an irreducible Markov chain NEVER has infinitely many stationary distributions. Actually, it has only one of them

Answer (score 0):

If the Markov chain is irreducible and aperiodic, then there is a unique stationary distribution, Additionally, in this case $P^k$ converges to a rank-one matrix in which each row is the stationary distribution $\pi$.

(This can be proved by using the fact that the Largest Eigenvalue of a Stochastic Matrix is $1$ and using perron-frobenius theorem(Perron projection)).

Now using that fact that $P=P^n$ for all natural number $n$ we trivially get the result as distinct constant sequences cannot converge to the same thing.